# Dart - Map vs Switch statement performance

Tags: dictionary, dart, switch-statement

In our flutter project, with use a lot of `enum`s and `extension`s. Some of us write `switch` statements, some others use `map`s. I was wondering what practice is considered the best one in terms of time, memory etc ?

```dart
enum Animal { cat, dog, bird }
```

Switch statement:

```dart
extension AnimalExtension on Animal {
    String get name {
        switch (this) {
            case Animal.cat:
                return 'Cat';
            case Animal.dog:
                return 'Dog';
            case Animal.bird:
                return 'Bird';
        }
    }
}
```

Map:

```dart
extension AnimalExtension on Animal {
    String get name => {
        Animal.cat: 'Cat',
        Animal.dog: 'Dog',
        Animal.bird: 'Bird',
    }[this];
}
```

---

Also, for the `map` method, is it better to create a `static const Map` instead of instantiating it on the fly at every call?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't worry about speed for something this small, not unless it's at the heart of the inner loop of your computation.

The switch has the chance to be more time efficient, the map will likely have less code (it reuses the `Map.[]` code). The map should definitely be const.

If you want to optimize performance *and* code size, I'd go with:

```dart
  String get name => const ['cat', 'dog', 'bird'][this.index];
```